# Preference Screen Text Not Resizing Properly

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I have a preference screen created from pref_screen.xml that is set from an activity that extends PreferenceActivity and implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.  When I change a setting, the text resizes too large.  Notice in the screen shots that the "Enable Severe Weather Alerts" is now too large.  My guess is the adapter the PreferenceActivity utilitizes.  Any idea how to stop? Or re-instantiate the entire view?Here is first load:
[image]

and here after I change "Notifications" from "Off" to "My Current Location"

[image]